# Editing XML file with Java

Tags: java, xml

I am new in Java and XML.
I need to modify a part of this XML file using a Java program :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Traduction>
  <Entrée>
    <Word1>Word1</Word1>
    <N1>0</N1>
    <N2>0</N2>
    <Word2>Word2</Word2>
  </Entrée>
  <Sortie>
    <Word1>Word1</Word1>
    <N1>0</N1>
    <N2>0</N2>
    <Word2>Word2</Word2>
  </Sortie>
</Traduction>
```

I wanted to use this code in Eclipse :

```
try {
    String filepath = "/home/user/Trad/ex1.xml";
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = builder.parse(filepath);

    Node Traduction = document.getChildNodes().item(0);
    Node Sortie = Traduction.getChildNodes().item(1);

    Sortie.getChildNodes().item(0).setTextContent("AAA");
    Sortie.getChildNodes().item(1).setTextContent("001");
    Sortie.getChildNodes().item(2).setTextContent("002");
    Sortie.getChildNodes().item(3).setTextContent("BBB");

    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(filepath));
    transformer.transform(source, result);
}

catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
    pce.printStackTrace();
    } 
catch (TransformerException tfe) {
    tfe.printStackTrace();
    } 
catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
    } 
catch (SAXException sae) {
    sae.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I get this result, which is not what I want :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><Traduction>
  <Entrée>AAA<Word1>001</Word1>002<N1>BBB</N1>
    <N2>0</N2>
    <Word2>Word2</Word2>
  </Entrée>
  <Sortie>
    <Word1>Word1</Word1>
    <N1>0</N1>
    <N2>0</N2>
    <Word2>Word2</Word2>
  </Sortie>
</Traduction>
```

I would like to get :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Traduction>
  <Entrée>
    <Word1>Word1</Word1>
    <N1>0</N1>
    <N2>0</N2>
    <Word2>Word2</Word2>
  </Entrée>
  <Sortie>
    <Word1>AAA</Word1>
    <N1>001</N1>
    <N2>002</N2>
    <Word2>BBB</Word2>
  </Sortie>
</Traduction>
```

What should I modify in my Java code to get this ?

Comment: read about Java naming convention. propertie names sould start with lowercase character

Comment: Ok, I am going to correct this.

Answer (score 2):

As already suggested, Dom Node can be of any type. You can use `getElementsByTagName` method to be sure of that.

E.g.:

```
try {
            String filepath = "/home/user/Trad/ex1.xml";
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse(filepath);

            Element sortie = (Element) document.getElementsByTagName("Sortie").item(0);

            sortie.getElementsByTagName("Word1").item(0).setTextContent("AAA");
            sortie.getElementsByTagName("N1").item(0).setTextContent("001");
            sortie.getElementsByTagName("N2").item(0).setTextContent("002");
            sortie.getElementsByTagName("Word2").item(0).setTextContent("BBB");

            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(filepath));
            transformer.transform(source, result);
        }

        catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            pce.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
            tfe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException sae) {
            sae.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be the most simple solution at first view.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is that DOM nodes can be other than the element nodes. I.e. for the whitespaces between `<Entree>` and `<Word1>` it creates a `TextNode`. You need to go through the `NodeList` and check for node name or node type.

In the code example you can see example for both. Please note that this code is a bit unstructured. For production quality code you might want to refactor it a little.

```
Node Traduction = document.getChildNodes().item(0);
NodeList traductionChildNodes = Traduction.getChildNodes();
Node Sortie = null;
for (int i = 0; i < traductionChildNodes.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = traductionChildNodes.item(i);
    // here we check the node name
    if ("Sortie".equals(node.getNodeName())) {
        Sortie = node;
        break;
    }
}

NodeList sortieChildNodes = Sortie.getChildNodes();
// we got the texts in an array so we can access them one after another
String[] texts = new String[] {"AAA", "001", "002", "BBB"};
// i is for the nodes, j is for the 
for (int nodeIndex = 0, textIndex = 0; nodeIndex < sortieChildNodes.getLength(); nodeIndex++) {
    Node node = sortieChildNodes.item(nodeIndex);
    // here we check the node type
    if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        node.setTextContent(texts[textIndex++]);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you might consider using [XPath](http://www.journaldev.com/1194/java-xpath-example-tutorial) because that makes ad-hoc XML processing a little more intuitive.

Comment: Thank you ! Indeed, I didn't know whitespaces could also be nodes. The result is correct now.